# Are GDrive and SkyDrive available via NuGet

Tags: c#, nuget, google-drive-api, onedrive

Does anyone know if NuGet packages exist for both Google’s GDrive and Microsoft’s SkyDrive? If not can anyone from Google or Microsoft say when they are likely to be released?

Note: I am aware that SDKs for [GDrive exist here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/) and [SkyDrive exist here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh826521).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Google Drive packages are not available on NuGet yet, but this is something that we are planning to do. Please star this feature request to get notified of all updates: http://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/detail?id=67

Comment: Thanks, any idea on how many stars are likely to be needed to become a feature?

Comment: I'm not sure a specific number of stars is required to turn that into reality, the good news is that the issue is assigned to the main contributor to the project and he seems really keen on implementing it.